# How can I create a dynamic array in a procedure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc, procedure

I'm new to this fantastic site and I found it very useful in many occasions, but now I'm dealing with a problem which I can't seem to solve.
I'm a beginner C student and I'm studying dynamic memory allocation.
I want to create a dynamic array of, let's say, integers, allocating memory for it inside a procedure, not in the main function.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int *numbers; // pointer to create a dynamic array
        int *test; // pointer to test realloc function
        int c;
        size_t i = 0;
        unsigned int dim; // array's length

        // allocate memory for the 1st number 
        numbers = malloc(sizeof(*numbers));
        if (numbers == NULL) {
                fputs("Error while allocating memory!\n", stderr);
        } else {
                printf("Insert the 1 number: ");
                scanf("%d", &numbers[0]);
                ++i;

                /* allocate memory for the other numbers,
                 * until the user inputs EOF
                 */
                while (!feof(stdin)) {
                        test = realloc(numbers, (sizeof(*numbers) * (i + 1)));
                        if (test == NULL) {
                                fputs("Error while allocating memory!\n", stderr);
                        } else {
                                numbers = test;
                                printf("Insert the %u number: ", i + 1);
                                scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
                                ++i;
                        }
                }
                dim = --i;

                // print the array, 5 numbers per line
                 for (i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
                        if (i % 5 == 0) {
                                puts("");
                        }
                        printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
                }
                puts("");
        }

        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

But I want to do this (which doesn't work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void get_numbers(int **numbers, unsigned int *dim);

int main()
{
        int *numbers; // pointer to create a dynamic array
        size_t i = 0;
        unsigned int dim; // array's length

        get_numbers(&numbers, &dim);

        // print the array, 5 numbers per line
         for (i = 0; i < dim; ++i) {
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                        puts("");
                }
                printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
        }
        puts("");

        getchar();
        return 0;
}

void get_numbers(int **numbers, unsigned int *dim)
{
        int *test; // pointer to test realloc function
        int c;
        size_t i = 0;

        // allocate memory for the 1st number 
        *numbers = malloc(sizeof(*numbers));
        if (*numbers == NULL) {
                fputs("Error while allocating memory!\n", stderr);
        } else {
                printf("Insert the 1 number: ");
                scanf("%d", &numbers[0]); // Maybe the error is here
                ++i;

                /* allocate memory for the other numbers,
                 * until the user inputs EOF
                 */
                while (!feof(stdin)) {
                        test = realloc(*numbers, (sizeof(*numbers) * (i + 1)));
                        if (test == NULL) {
                                fputs("Error while allocating memory!\n", stderr);
                        } else {
                                *numbers = test;
                                printf("Insert the %u number: ", i + 1);
                                scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
                                ++i;
                        }
                }
                *dim = --i;
        }
}
```

Do I need to use a pointer to a pointer to int, right?
I know I made some mistakes but I can't figure out how to fix them.
Thanks in advance for your replies!
Bye,
Fabio Nardelli

Comment: `scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);` --> `scanf("%d", &(*numbers)[i]);` or `scanf("%d",  *numbers + i);`, `sizeof(*numbers)` --> `sizeof(**numbers)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Many thanks!! It works!!!!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What if I have an array of struct? For example struct data *p; Should the scanf be (*p)[i].field?

Comment: `p[i].field` .... `struct data { int field; } x[10], *p = x;`.. `scanf("%d", &p[i].field);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXI p[i].field doesn't work, while (*p)[i].field does. Anyway, in the code I posted, they work both sizeof(*numbers) and sizeof(**numbers). Why?

Comment: Because `int` and `int *` are same size on your system.

Comment: Thanks! I made confusion because I'm using a struct whose fields are strings

Comment: `void func(struct data **p, int i){ scanf("%d", &(*p)[i].field); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first block of code, `numbers` is of type `int*`.
In the second block of code, `numbers` is of type `int**`.

You have not fixed all the places that need to be fixed because of that change.

My suggestion:

1. Change the input argument to `numbersPtr`.
2. Create a local variable `int* numbers`.
3. Before you return from the function, set `*numbersPtr` to `number`.

---

```
void get_numbers(int **numbersPtr, unsigned int *dim)
{
   int* numbers;

   ...

   *numbersPtr = numbers;
}
```

It will be better to change `get_numbers` to return `numbers`.

```
int* get_numbers(unsigned int *dim)
{
   int* numbers;

   ...

   return numbers;
}
```

and change its usage as:

```
numbers = get_numbers(&dim);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So you mean to use numbers in the scanf?

Comment: @FabioNardelli, use `numbers` just like you used it  in the first block of code.

Comment: Even better: the array is an OUTPUT from the get_numbers function, so make it the return value instead of using an argument:  `int *get_numbers(unsigned *dim)`...  ending with `return numbers;`

Comment: @ChrisDodd, much better suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks, but I think I'm forced to use void functions(it's for a homework at university).